# Using MS Help Viewer in a new application

Tags: help-viewer-1.0

I want to use MS Help Viewer to create a help system for our application. The documentation [suggests](http://www.helpware.net/mshelp3/intro.htm) this is possible. I found however no way to install the Local Help Viewer and the required Help Library Agent which is supposed to intercept and process help requests without installing visual studio. I also see no obvious way on how to integrate Help Library Manager in a new application: where is the API and the docs? I can find neither in HelpViewer SDK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the moment (sept 2011) it looks like MS Help Viewer is not designed to be used outside Visual Studio although things may change in the future. Waiting for an announcement from MS.